# Does processing occur locally or remotely when piping from an AWS CLI file stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

When dealing with file streams using the AWS CLI (see "Downloading an S3 object as a local file stream" in the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html)), does any processing performed on the stream occur AWS server side, or on the machine which executed the command?

To provide an example of what I mean, assume `some_process` below is a perl script or something like that which processes streaming data.

If I would execute:

```bash
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/unprocessed_stream.txt - | \
some_process | \
aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/processed_stream.txt
```

Should the `some_process` perl script be executed AWS server side (without downloading the data locally) or locally (implying the `-` character in the `aws s3 cp` command performs a download).

Comment: That command downloads data, feeds it to a local process started via `some_process`, then uploading the results.  So, the direct answer to your question is "locally".

Comment: This is what I was wondering @AnonCoward. It was unclear to me if a download would be performed or not if both the start and end destination of the file were remote on s3.

Happy to accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the pipes, you are running three commands:

```
aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/unprocessed_stream.txt -
some_process
aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/processed_stream.txt
```

Each of those three commands run on your local machine.  The first and second obviously use network resources to some extent, but still, `aws` is running your local machine.  Just as `some_process`, the only thing the `|` operator adds is that the output from the first command is feed to the second as input, and so on.

In other words, `some_process` is running locally.  It may, of course, reach out and do things with network resources, but that would be work initiated by your local machine.